# Containing a SVG image within Flexbox

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I've managed to create a split screen layout in flexbox.

On my left side I've set an inside container to hold content. The first piece of content is another container with a tall SVG image.

I've outlined the containers to make it easier to see their placement in my live example below.

The two containers are outlined in red (outer) and green(inner). What I want to accomplish is when bottom of the red container hits the green container, the green container shrinks within the red, thus down-scaling the SVG. Not sure if this relies on the properties of the inner container, SVG or both.

**HTML**

```
<main class="row space-between">
  <section class="column w50 vh100 center" style="background: #1e1e1e">
    <div class="column w75 h75 top-center" style="border: 1px solid red">
      <div class="w100 center pt1 pb1" style="border: 1px solid green">
        <div class="phoneContainer center w100 depth-1" style="position: relative; height: 500px">

          <svg class="absolute depth-1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMidmeet" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 497 1014" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <title>Apple iPhone 6</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
              <path id="Apple-iPhone-6" d="M494,290 L495.501424,290 C496.329065,290 497,289.328711 497,288.501847 L497,216.498153 C497,215.670746 496.33497,215 495.501424,215 L494,215 L494,74.9994014 C494,33.5783758 460.420697,0 418.993513,0 L78.0064869,0 C36.5815481,0 3,33.5749963 3,74.9994014 L3,128 L1.49857602,128 C0.670935336,128 0,128.677424 0,129.507836 L0,167.492164 C0,168.324919 0.665029764,169 1.49857602,169 L3,169 L3,215 L1.49857602,215 C0.670935336,215 0,215.671289 0,216.498153 L0,288.501847 C0,289.329254 0.665029764,290 1.49857602,290 L3,290 L3,307 L1.49857602,307 C0.670935336,307 0,307.671289 0,308.498153 L0,380.501847 C0,381.329254 0.665029764,382 1.49857602,382 L3,382 L3,939.000599 C3,980.421624 36.5793027,1014 78.0064869,1014 L418.993513,1014 C460.418452,1014 494,980.425004 494,939.000599 L494,290 Z M33,123 L33,889 L464,889 L464,123 L33,123 Z M248,983 C268.98682,983 286,965.98682 286,945 C286,924.01318 268.98682,907 248,907 C227.01318,907 210,924.01318 210,945 C210,965.98682 227.01318,983 248,983 Z M248,979 C266.777681,979 282,963.777681 282,945 C282,926.222319 266.777681,911 248,911 C229.222319,911 214,926.222319 214,945 C214,963.777681 229.222319,979 248,979 Z M170,72 C174.418278,72 178,68.418278 178,64 C178,59.581722 174.418278,56 170,56 C165.581722,56 162,59.581722 162,64 C162,68.418278 165.581722,72 170,72 Z M249,37 C251.761424,37 254,34.7614237 254,32 C254,29.2385763 251.761424,27 249,27 C246.238576,27 244,29.2385763 244,32 C244,34.7614237 246.238576,37 249,37 Z M212.994583,60 C210.788436,60 209,61.7953562 209,64 C209,66.209139 210.78308,68 212.994583,68 L285.005417,68 C287.211564,68 289,66.2046438 289,64 C289,61.790861 287.21692,60 285.005417,60 L212.994583,60 Z"
              fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
            </g>
          </svg>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
  <section class="column w50 vh100 center bg-white">
    <div class="column w75 h75 center" style="border: 1px solid red">
      <div class="h100" style="border: 1px solid blue">
        <h2>Title Text Box</h2></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
svg {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.pt1 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.pb1 {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.column {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: auto;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .column {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .row>.column {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}

.w50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.w75 {
  width: 75%;
}

.w100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.vh100 {
  height: 100vh;
}

.h75 {
  height: 75%;
}

.h100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column.top-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column.top-center {
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.space-between {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.depth-1 {
  z-index: 100;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Office Code Pro;
  src: url(../fonts/OfficeCodePro-Regular.woff);
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #222;
  color: #2c6284;
}

::selection {
  background: #222;
  color: #2c6284;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
  font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Live Code example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZoXgE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some inline styles on `.phoneContainer`.

```
style="position: relative; height: 500px"
```

Remove the `500px` height and replace it with `100vh`.

```
style="position: relative; height: 100vh"
```

[image]

Comment: Looping around... what would the best way to go about setting an image within the phone and having that scale in the same way? Set up a container that matches the dimensions of the inside of the phone, then `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` on the images?

Comment: I believe so, but it's tough to say for sure without live code.